# How to drill into a wall that likely has electrical wires in the area?

Tags: electrical

I have to install a baby gate at the top of our stairs (our little one just started to crawl). However, at the top of the stairs there is a light switch which means there could be electrical wires running vertically or horizontally. The baby gate needs to be installed almost directly below the light switch. I opened the switch receptacle and there is indeed wire coming from the top and going out the bottom.

Are there any tips for drilling into the wall to avoid hitting the electrical wire? There is no other spot to put the baby gate so I need to find a way to make it work. Internet searches only yield ways to avoid drilling in an area with an electrical wire... not what to do when you don't have a choice.

Comment: With a baby gate you will want the screws to go into studs(no drywall anchors).  Wires are usually beside(on the side) of studs.  Light switches(or outlets) also screwed to side of studs.    Said almost directly below, do you mean maybe an inch from the edge of switch?

Comment: You could try using a baby gate that uses presdure pads against the wall, thus no drilling.  These are readily available and very effective.

Comment: @Chenmunka You should ***never*** use a pressure-fit baby gate at the top of stairs. If someone (even a toddler) leans on it hard enough, it will fall down the stairs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at outlet locations is not how we locate wires.

Modern Codes require that dangerous or messy utilities (electric, gas, plumbing) must be a certain depth beneath the finished surface, OR, guarded by a fairly thick metal plate.  So the rules for you are:

- Don't drill more than 1-1/4" deep. Use mechanical stops to assure that doesn't happen (e.g. corks on the drill bit).
- Don't use screws that penetrate more than 1-1/4".
- If you hit something really hard, DON'T treat it as a challenge lol.  Take the hint and back off.

Note that the standard wall material, drywall, is basically a sheet of chalkboard chalk lined with sheets of paper (actually that gives it too much credit; drywall crumbles much easier than chalkboard chalk).  As such, **drywall has no structural strength at all**.  Desperately needing to attach something somewhere, does not make the drywall any stronger.  It will simply pull out and make a BIG mess requiring drywall patch and repaint.

Find the wood studs; those are the only things you can expect strength from.  If you are fixated on a particular location *between* studs, then buy a nice thick 7/8" piece of plywood wide enough to attach to both studs securely.  That plywood then provides the structural "meat" to mount your item.

Comment: Thanks, I like the idea of using a piece of wood to attach to the nearest studs!

Answer (score 0):

I'd start armed with a stud & cable detector. These are cheap & more likely to give false positives than false negatives, which is safer than the other way round. Start at high sensitivity & drop as you get closer to your intended 'find'.

Search for 'Stud Finder Wall Scanner'.

As it is common to run cabling down the side of a stud [& rare as hen's teeth to run it down the face] then you will find them very close but be able to identify which side of the stud to avoid drilling. The light switch position will give a hint, but it's best to be certain.
You won't really know until you scan it whether the cables drop from above or rise from below.